# Склонение женской фамилии заканчивающуюся на ударную - а (Бела)

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Добрый день! 
Встал вопрос, причем встал ребром. Чуть ли не крики и сопли. 
Я сказал: «Возьми у Белы» что-либо. На великого знатока русского языка я не претендую. Поэтому обращаюсь к вам :)

Фамилия греческого происхождения ж.р. Бела, ударение на - а.

Я прочитал правила склонения, и мне кажется все-таки, что эта фамилия склоняется.

Что скажете?

Спасибо за интерес)

Answer (score 1):

Правило таково: Фамилии иного происхождения (славянские, ***из восточных языков, а греческий относится к восточногерманской подгруппе:)*** склоняются по первому склонению, т. е. в них вычленяется ударное окончание -а.

См.:  Н. А. Еськова. Трудности словоизменения существительных. Учебно-методические материалы к практическим занятиям по курсу «Язык современной печати». Госкомитет печати СССР. Всесоюзный институт повышения квалификации работников печати. М., 1990.

Дополнение: В приложении к словарю к ***"Словарю русских личных имен" А.В. Суперанской (М., 2005)*** содержится следующая рекомендация:

> "Нестандартные русские и нерусские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на -а, -я (кроме французских с ударением на последнем слоге: Дюма, Золя), склоняются по типу существительных кора, каша, земля, капля. <...> Фамилии этого типа у мужчин и женщин склоняются в единственном числе одинаково, Во множественном числе они остаются неизменяемыми, сохраняющими форму именительного падежа единственного числа. Ударение на основе или окончании в зависимости от формы именительного падежа единственного числа". Это значит, что греческая фамилия ***Белла*** с ударным конечным гласным ***должна склоняться.***

Comment: Мне почему-то помнится, что женские фамилии не склоняются, только мужские.

Comment: Правило относится и к женским фамилиям.

Comment: Не склоняются женские и мужские фамилии французского происхождения с ударным -а.

Comment: Спасибо Серж, Вы сделали мой день! :)

Comment: Иностранные фамилии, оканчивающиеся на гласный звук (кроме неударяемых -а, -я), не склоняются, например: романы Золя, открытия Араго, драмы Гюго, оперы Бизе, музыка Пуччини, пьесы Шоу.
Из фамилий на ударяемые -а склоняются только славянские: у писателя Майбороды, к философу Сковороде.
справочник по правописанию и стилистике

Comment: Максим, посмотрите на Грамоте.ру. Именно там говорится о правиле, которое я привел.

Comment: [Н. А. Еськова. Особенности склонения фамилий и личных имен](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_482)